# Invoking Ghostscript from PHP: Unable to open the initial device

Tags: php, ghostscript

I have installed Ghostscript from MacPorts, and am trying to invoke it from a PHP script to extract single page from a multi-page PDF file and then output it. My code looks like this:

```
<?php

$cmd = '/opt/local/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE \
    -dBATCH -dSAFER -dFirstPage=20 -dLastPage=20
    -sOutputFile=%stdout  "/path/to/input/pdf.pdf"';

// Will uncomment this when it works
// header("Content-Type: application/pdf");

putenv("GS_LIB=/opt/local/share/ghostscript/9.02/lib");
putenv("GS_FONTPATH=/opt/local/share/ghostscript/fonts");
putenv("TMPDIR=/tmp");

passthru($cmd);
```

When I hit this script in a web browser, I see:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.02 (2011-03-30) Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.
All rights reserved. This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file
PUBLIC for details. **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
```

The same command works from a shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The apache/webserver user likely does not have the permissions or the same environment variables.  Perhaps try sudo, or make sure apache has proper permissions.

Comment: The Apache user has read access to the source PDF, as well as read/write access to the TMPDIR. I'm not sure what else might be required. I've tried adding all of my shell's environment variables using putenv(), with the same result.

Comment: @alexantd What happens if you try sudo in your $cmd and run it as the user from who's command line it worked.

Comment: I have been fighting with this all morning, and I have no idea what I did, but the exact same code works now. Thanks :)

Comment: Setting the chmod permissions to 0777 for the directory where the shell script is located, solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error too, and it took me 5 hours to figure out what the solution to it was. Notice the difference between these two code blocks:

```
$cmd = '/opt/local/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE \
    -dBATCH -dSAFER -dFirstPage=20 -dLastPage=20
    -sOutputFile=%stdout  "/path/to/input/pdf.pdf"';

$cmd = '/opt/local/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE \
    -dBATCH -dSAFER -dFirstPage=20 -dLastPage=20 \
    -sOutputFile=%stdout  "/path/to/input/pdf.pdf"';
```

The shell doesn't appreciate the unexpected linebreaks, so by just adding a backslash \ in front of every newline, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the `**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.` error message when using PHP to call a pdf generation script.

I was following the path of permissions and options, and stumbled upon something entirely by accident.  I wasn't assigning enough memory to PHP to complete the transaction.

I added:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "2048M");
```

prior to invoking my generation script and it completed without error.  Memory obviously might be excessive, but you can adjust as required.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by removing the double quotes in thе line:

```
$cmd = '/opt/local/bin/gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE \
-dBATCH -dSAFER -dFirstPage=20 -dLastPage=20
-sOutputFile=%stdout  /path/to/input/pdf.pdf';
```

Tested with shell_exec on PHP+Ubuntu18.4+Apache2.4